# Python virutalenv issues, tried the --no-site-packages and got this

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages foobar
New python executable in foobar/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
```

What happened here?

```
lsvirtualenv
```

returns nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.

An env created by `virtualenv --no-site-packages foobar` will not be seen by the virtualenvwrapper functions, such as `lsvirtualenv`.

If you want to tap the unbridled power of the virtualenvwrapper, follow [these](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/install.html) instructions and create a new env by `mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages foobar`